# MongoDB: $match on a nested document after $lookup

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I need to query a collection of timecards which are linked to jobs, while jobs are linked to facilities with a specific facility ID. I have the following aggregation query:

```
Timecard.aggregate([
    { $match: query }, //some query parameters set before, doesn't matter here
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'jobs',
            as: 'job',
            localField: 'job',
            foreignField: '_id'
        }
    },
    { $unwind: '$job' },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'facilities',
            localField: 'job.facilityId'
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'job.facilityId'
        }
    },
    { $unwind: '$job.facilityId' },
    { $match: {'job.facilityId._id':'5cad048d95d61a002f5a9edb'}}
];)
```

Everything before the last $match works just fine, jobs are populated into timecards, facilities are populated into jobs. But the match doesn't work for some reason. However, if I add facilityId field with

```
{$addFields: {facilityId: '$job.facilityId._id'}}
```

and change the $match to

```
{$match: 'facilityId':'5cad048d95d61a002f5a9edb'}
```

then it works.
The question is, is there a way to query a subdocument's field with dot notation this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last line likely needs to be an ObjectId

```
{ $match: {'job.facilityId._id': ObjectId('5cad048d95d61a002f5a9edb')}}
```

Comment: brilliant! thanks, i thought i tried it before tho... however, usual mongoose queries deal with strings instead of ObjectId's just fine

Comment: @Artem - Ahh, yeah you are correct. mongoose checks if the field you are querying against is an ObjectId and converts it for you. It doesn't do that for aggregation queries (it would be extremely difficult to implement that), so it just passes it straight to mongo without converting.